# What is the most efficient and well presented version of this code?

Tags: python, pep8, coding-efficiency

I'm trying to make a class which creates empty board objects as part of a board game project. Here's what I came up with :

```
class Board:
    board = []
    # Initially the board is empty

    def __init__(self, size=9):
        # If n is the size of the board
        # Each line is a list of n colums
        # Each column is initially set as a list of n empty squares
        for line in range(size):
            list = []
            for columns in range(size):
                list.append("O")
            self.board.append(list)
        return None

    def __repr__(self):
        # Lines separator is '\n'
        # Columns separator is ' '
        repr = ''
        for n_line in range(len(self.board)):
            for n_column in range(len(self.board[n_line])):
                repr += self.board[n_line][n_column] + ' '
            repr += '\n'
        return repr
```

Comment: If this is **working code** that you think could be improved, see [codereview.se]. If not, please clarify the problem with it.

Comment: `board` is currently an attribute of the `Board` class.  That means that each `Board` instance will share a single `board`.

Comment: `self.board = [['O'] * size for _ in range(size)]`

Comment: Please check ["Which site?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in) for general issues and ["Code Review or not?"](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users/5778#5778)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Regardless of whether it works or not, this question needs a lot of clarification before it's a decent question anywhere.

Comment: The “most efficient version" of this code is almost certainly a C extension module with handcoded inline assembly that uses the Python API as little as possible and has as much of the data pre-built in static variables as possible. Are you really interested in that? If not, why are you asking for “more efficient”?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your class can be improved. As pointed out in the comments, `board` should be an instance attribute, not a a class attribute which can be concisely initiated with a list comprehension. Moreover, proper use of `str` methods will drastically shorten your `__repr__` as well:

```
class Board:
    # don't make board a class attribute

    def __init__(self, size=9):
        self.board = [["O"] * size for _ in range(size)]

    def __repr__(self):
        return '\n'.join(' '.join(line) for line in self.board)
        # Or more fanciful
        # return '\n'.join(map(' '.join, self.board))

>>> b = Board()
>>> b
O O O O O O O O O
O O O O O O O O O
O O O O O O O O O
O O O O O O O O O
O O O O O O O O O
O O O O O O O O O
O O O O O O O O O
O O O O O O O O O
O O O O O O O O O
```